# Unable to add action for uisearchbar using storyboard xcode 5

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, xcode5

I am trying to add an action for my `UISearchBar` button to my `UIViewController`.

I CTRL+drag from the bar to the .h or .m file of my `UIViewController`.

When I CTRL+drag from the storyboard to the .m file nothing happens.

And when I drag to the .h file it just gives the option for adding an outlet or an outlet connection. See the screen shot:

[image: Storyboard screenshot]

I am able to add an action to the other `UIViewController`s but for this particular `UIViewController` I cannot add any actions by CTRL+dragging to it.

I am displaying my view controller in a `UITabBarController`. Is there something related to this?

Comment: @Bigood , thanks for your comment. I am not sure that understood the exact meaning of your question. but I am trying to add connect a uisearch of my uiviewcontroller to .m file of my class.

Comment: It seems that you removed your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add an action to `UISearchBar` because it is not a `UIControl`. Instead:

1. Set your view controller as the delegate of the search bar. You can achieve that by selecting the search bar in the storyboard and CTRL+drag a line to the round yellow symbol for the view controller. Then in the pop up menu choose `delegate`.

   [image]
2. Go to the .h file of your view controller class and add `<UISearchBarDelegate>` at the end of the line `@interface YourViewController : UIViewController` to make your view controller confrom to `UISearchBarDelegate` protocol.
3. No go to the .m file of your view controller class and implement the delegate method that you need, i.e.

   ```
   - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
       // your code
   }
   ```

There are corresponding methods for the cancel button, the bookmark button and the results list button. See [Apple Docs on the UISearchBarDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchBarDelegate).